# @media system.media is a namespace

Tags: css, media-queries

I am trying to copy some examples of using media queries into a view in an MVC5 web project

eg   - @Media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {}

but it always gives an error

```
system.media is a namespace and cannot be used as an expression
```

how can I get round this? Do I need additional files or references?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that @@ is required for Razor vbhtml pages

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        body {  background-color: yellow;}

@@Media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>The @@Media Rule</h1>

    <p>Resize the browser window. When the width of this document is 600 pixels or less, the background-color is "lightblue", otherwise it is "yellow".</p>

</body>
</html>
```